# GWT compilation failed

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, compiler-errors

I am developping a GWT Application and when I was about to compile I got a message "GWT Compilation Failed" without any stacktrace.

Then I've tried something even simpler, like creating the sample application and I've got "Creation of element failed. Reason: Invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed".

I did a lot of research and tried a lot of stuff (change folder permissions, deactivate antivirus, changed version of eclipse and gwt, checked windows event logger (found nothing), recreate workspace, remove ClassPath environment variavble...). The most weird thing is that in my personal computer everything works fine, but copying the eclipse folder to my work's computer I get always the same problems.

This is the .log from eclipse.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 10001 2014-05-19 17:07:17.829
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 0] Invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed. See the error log for more details.
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5204)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed. See the error log for more details.
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.runtime.tools.WebAppProjectCreatorRunner.createProject(WebAppProjectCreatorRunner.java:70)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.createGWTProject(WebAppProjectCreator.java:683)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.create(WebAppProjectCreator.java:292)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.NewWebAppProjectWizard.finishPage(NewWebAppProjectWizard.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$2.run(NewElementWizard.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5204)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
!SUBENTRY 1 com.google.gwt.eclipse.core 4 0 2014-05-19 17:07:17.829
!MESSAGE Invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed. See the error log for more details.
```

Does anyone has any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Check the JDK version set for the project.

Comment: Please try it again after removing all the generated stub and re-compiling the project again.

Comment: I tried jdk1.6.0_45, jdk1.7.0_51, jdk1.7.0_55, jdk1.8.0_05 and none of them worked. The problem is certainly deeper. Especially because jdk1.8.0_05 and jdk1.7.0_51 works in my personal computer.

Another weird thing is that it works if I execute by cmd.

Comment: Moreover, there is no generated stub. It does not generate anything, for any project (new or old).

Comment: How did you imported the project into Eclipse. Use **Import** functionally of Eclipse.

Comment: I used the import functionality. That's not the problem. I would guess that the problem is some configuration conflict. But I couldn't discover what it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed ClassPath entry from Windows Environment Variables and it did the trick.